# How to $compile a directive on an dynamically created SVG element

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to add a context-menu directive to a dynamically created SVG element.

In an AngularJS Controller, I define my svg as follows:

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg-canvas").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .append('g');
```

Later on, I appended a rectangle to it as below. Note that, I add an attribute of "ng-context-menu", my AngularJS directive.

```
svg.append("rect")
.attr("x", 35)
.attr("y", 15)
.attr("width", 20)
.attr("height", 20)
.attr("ng-context-menu", "")
.style("fill", "gray");
```

I add this code, after the DOM is loaded, thus, this code is not compiled with AngularJS. This means that context-menu is not binded to the element.

I add the full working code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/aZB5F/2/), in case you want to check :)

Do you have any suggestions to make it work? Do I need to create a directive for it?

Answer (score 8):

You can inject $compile service and used it to compile #svg-canvas.

```
$compile(angular.element('#svg-canvas'))($scope);
```

Checkout your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZB5F/4/)

If you want to compile any d3 element, use

```
$compile(element[0][0])(scope)
```

You can find it here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZB5F/5/) (but be aware, that in this snippet actually the 'g' element is compiled, not the whole svg)

Comment: GrizzlyNetch, thank you for your reply. They both work. However, when I want to go into the menu, the menu disappeared. Do you have any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Well...You have it in the directive in mouseleave event. Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/aZB5F/6/ I've commented out the mouseleave event handler :)

Comment: Thanks @JakubKnejzlik I solved my issue as well following ur suggestion